# Publish Word Addin to Shared Folder

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am creating a Word add in, and publish to Shared Folder, but I got error "Cannot find ‘file://xx/Word/home.html?_host_Info=Word|Win32|16.01|en-US". If I enter this address in the IE, it shows up correctly.
I follow below links.
[Build your first Word add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins)
In addition, please ignore the different name for shared folder, I made twice test, and I shared the unconsistency name.

Thanks for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPT3v.png)

Comment: Where did you see that error message?

Comment: Screenshot would help too.

Comment: After I insert the add in from Shared Folder in Word, you could see screehshot in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image/description, I think the issue is with the way you're sharing your folder, or what you're adding to the trusted-catalogs entry.

There should be no "file://". Instead, once you've shared a folder with yourself, you should be able to see it as \computer-name\mymanifestfolder.

If you show a screenshot of what you have in your trusted catalog, and how you've shared the folder, I could help further.

EDIT: Thinking on it some more, it might be a manifest issue instead.  Could you share what you have in your manifest?  Note that instead of pointing to a file:// location, you'll want to host your files on an IIS host (localhost, azure, git + rawgit), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I move home.html and home.js to IIS, it works correctly. But could you tell me why it did not work with putting these two files in Shared Folder? Based on the link, it seems it should be work by storing them in Shared Folder. I shared the folder follow [Share a Folder or Drive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The Network path for Shared Folder is \\my windows name\Word, trusted-catalogs is \\my windows name\Word. My manifest value is "<SourceLocation DefaultValue="\\my windows name\Word\home.html" />".

Comment: Not sure about why a network path didn't work for the file-hosting... but I can tell you that even if it *does* work, I would strongly recommend against it.  Your add-in will eventually run off of a web server rather than a file server, and I think there are some subtle differences in the way that browsers treat files versus real https urls.